# For which function are the fixed-points enumerated by $\phi_0(\alpha)$?

Tags: ordinals

In the Veblen function $\phi_1(\alpha)=\varepsilon_\alpha$ are fixed points of $\phi_0(\alpha)=\omega^\alpha$. It seems logical that $\phi_0(\alpha)=\omega^\alpha$ are fixed points of some other function - however I haven't been able to figure out which function has fixed-points enumerated by $\phi_0(\alpha)$.

**For which function are the fixed-points enumerated by $\phi_0(\alpha)$?**

Comment: If this was a fixed point enumeration, why would it not be $\phi_1$, pushing $\alpha\mapsto\varepsilon_\alpha$ to be $\phi_2$, etc.?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are essentially asking if there is a $\phi_{-1}(\alpha)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Correct.

Comment: And I am asking, if there was a natural and reasonable $\phi_{-1}$, why didn't it already take place as $\phi_0$ (and thus "pushing the index" of the rest of the hierarchy by 1)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. So then the answer is "there is no such function".

Comment: I didn't say that. I'm just asking, what would be the motivation, you think, for doing something like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My motivation in asking is that I was playing around with the Veblen function in the context of surreal numbers. I was able to work out things like $\phi_0(1/2)=\sqrt{\omega}$ and $\phi_0(-1)=1/\omega=\varepsilon$, which led me to contemplate things like $\phi_{1/2}(\alpha)$, $\phi_{-1}(\alpha)$ and $\phi_\varepsilon(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2):

Although $\phi_0$ doesn't enumerate the fixed points of any "elementary" function, it enumerates the so called *indecomposable ordinals*: an ordinal is said to be indecomposable if it can't be obtained as the sum of two smaller ordinals, and it turns out that such ordinals are precisely the powers of $\omega$ (the only exception is $0$: it is not a power of $\omega$, but it would make sense to say that it is indecomposable, since you can't construct anything from an empty set).

Anyway, if you really want, you can definitely construct a function $f$ whose fixed points are $0$ and the powers of $\omega$ (notice that, if you want $f$ to be normal like the ordinary Veblen functions, $f(1)=1$ forces $f(0)=0$). I didn't check all the details, but this should work:

- $f(0)=0$;
- $\forall \beta, \; f(\omega^\beta)=\omega^\beta$;
- if $\alpha=\omega^{\beta_1}+\omega^{\beta_2}+...+\omega^{\beta_k}$, where $k \ge 2$ and $\beta_1 \ge \beta_2 \ge ... \ge \beta_k$, then $f(\alpha)=\omega^{\beta_1}+\alpha$.